# SSD Firmware update = loss of data?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, updates, firmware

I recently got a new SSD (OCZ Vertex Plus) and after reading the helpful answers for my post [Disk Corruption = Failing Drive/Bad sectors?](https://superuser.com/questions/328114/disk-corruption-failing-drive-bad-sectors) I would like to try updating the firmware but the OCZ Firmware download site (http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/) warns me that I may lose data.

Is this just a disclaimer in case the update goes wrong?  Is it wrong to assume that if the update is successful, I should not lose my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done firmware updates on OCZ drives without losing all the data(these were on vertex 2s and 3s).  I think it is safe to assume you won't.  However with SSDs having a backup is always a good thing, as they fail early and fail often!

Comment: Yeah, there is a *very small* chance that the update might fail.

Comment: As Im sure the firmware installer will say, as most do, backup your data.  However, the likelihood of failure is extremely low.

Comment: True, but low > 0