# Will data remain intact when flashing the firmware of a “bricked” Intel SSD 520 Series SSD drive?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, firmware

My [Intel SSD 520 Series 240GB SSDSC2BW240A3L SSD](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/66250/intel-ssd-520-series-240gb-2-5in-sata-6gbs-25nm-mlc.html) featuring the [SandForce SF-2281VB1-SDC](https://www.techinsights.com/products/exr-1211-202) controller spontaneously died and does not show up in BIOS. Presumably, its firmware has been corrupted by a hardware failure of my laptop. It’s effectively a bricked SSD and I am attempting to restore the data myself.

The SSD allows writing firmware directly into the SandForce NAND controller via what is called “safe mode” (power-on with hardware-jumper *physically* set).

This procedure seems to be significantly different than what the manufacturer would consider the “normal“ way to flash firmware (like the ATA `hdparm --fwdownload`. Instead the “safe mode“  of the controller chip makes the SSD show up as a small block device (`SandForce{200026BB} (20DABBR0)`) with 32kiB of zeros, probably allowing to write a firmware onto it).

Note: Flashing the firmware using the manufacturers official software is not possible, as the SSD does not show up in BIOS when powering the SSD without the *physical safe-mode jumper* and thus won't get recognized by the updater.

#### Will data remain intact when flashing a recent image of the firmware of an Intel SSD 520 Series SSD drive using its “safe mode?”

FWIW, [similar question has been asked 10 years ago](https://superuser.com/q/328135/167207), but I wonder whether it is the case also, *specifically* when using the “safe mode“ of the controller chip.

---

**Normal Mode** -> `dmesg`

```
[298464.007969] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[298469.039922] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[298469.042071] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[298474.395841] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[298479.075840] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[298484.415762] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[298489.135759] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[298494.451690] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[298524.159446] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[298524.159451] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[298529.199417] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[298529.199425] ata1: reset failed, giving up
```

**Safe Mode** -> `dmesg`

```
[298648.794326] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[298648.794570] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[298648.794587] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[298648.794589] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[298648.794592] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[298648.795390] ata1.00: ATA-8: SandForce{200026BB}, 20DABBR0, max UDMA/133
[298648.795407] ata1.00: 64 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[298648.798939] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[298648.798954] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[298648.798956] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[298648.798958] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[298648.801010] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[298648.801158] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SandForce{200026 BBR0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[298648.801561] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[298648.801572] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 64 512-byte logical blocks: (32.8 kB/32.0 KiB)
[298648.801575] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[298648.801591] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[298648.801594] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[298648.801622] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[298648.862521] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[298652.279511] audit: type=1107 audit(1640838982.620:6116): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298652.282085] audit: type=1107 audit(1640838982.620:6117): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298657.120802] audit: type=1107 audit(1640838987.460:6118): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298657.122823] audit: type=1107 audit(1640838987.460:6119): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298673.280746] audit: type=1107 audit(1640839003.620:6120): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298673.280749] audit: type=1107 audit(1640839003.620:6121): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298679.622418] audit: type=1107 audit(1640839009.964:6122): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[298679.625168] audit: type=1107 audit(1640839009.964:6123): pid=1577 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=121400 label="snap.flameshot.flameshot" peer_pid=1578 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I updated the question to include diy flashing an image using the "safe mode".

Comment: This SSD supports hardware encryption. I’d say this elevates the risk involved with this operation. But you won’t be getting the data back if you don’t try either.

Comment: This question at this point is very clear. I have upvoted it and removed my vote to close. But [I just edited it](https://superuser.com/posts/1696562/revisions) because the reality is that kind of bolding of every other word will not make people take you any more seriously. Right now this is a unique case so I would just recommend you leave the question as-is right now. You will not score points or make things any clearer of you bold words and add odd code formatting. This is definitely a good question. Please be patient.

Comment: @Semnodime May I ask how the safe mode is enabled on those SSDs? I found nothing searching the web. Thank you.

Comment: @Semnodime Did you manage to update the firmware without losing your data?